# SSRS: Add +1 image based on amount

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a dynamic representation with images. Based on the initial value above I would like to display a certain amount of images. For example, I want to display the value 52 and underneath I want to display 5 images.

Please look at the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSJZ.png

Is this possible or do I need to have the images "pre-made" for this to work? I have no problem showing a single image based on a certain value...

Comment: Wow, never thought of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: moved my comment as answer, since it helped you please mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of ways might be putting all your images onto SSRS report and just set visibility of it based on expression. If you can do it for one, doing for many should be easy aswell just use AND in your expression